# Swift - assign value to related CoreData entity

Tags: swift, core-data, relationship

I'm building an app that has two CoreData entities - Workouts and Exercises. The relationship between the two is many-to-many.

The app is a pair of basic tableViewControllers that allow you to add a workout (workoutName) to the Workouts entity and then to add exercises to that Workout in the next tableViewController. What I'm struggling with is how to assign each exercise back to the workout it originates from in CoreData. Essentially what I'm trying to do is to set the workoutName value in the Workouts entity when I add a newExercise (using the exerciseName variable) to the Exercises entity.

I have the workoutName being passed to the Exercise tableViewController as var workout through the segue from the Workouts tableViewController.

I also have the many-to-many relationships and set up as NSSets in the NSManagedObjects files but don't know how to use them.

Here's the tableViewController for the exercise set up:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ExerciseMasterTableViewController: UITableViewController {

// Declare workout variable
var workout: Workouts!

// Create an empty array of Exercises
var exercises = [Exercises]()

// Retreive the managedObjectContext from AppDelegate
let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Use optional binding to confirm the managedObjectContext
    if let moc = self.managedObjectContext {
    }

    fetchExercises()
}

func fetchExercises() {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Exercises")

    // Create a sort descriptor object that sorts on the "exerciseName"
    // property of the Core Data object
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "exerciseName", ascending: true)

    // Set the list of sort descriptors in the fetch request,
    // so it includes the sort descriptor
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    if let fetchResults = managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil) as? [Exercises] {
        exercises = fetchResults
    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // How many rows are there in this section?
    // There's only 1 section, and it has a number of rows
    // equal to the number of exercises, so return the count
    return exercises.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Exercise Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    // Get the Exercises for this index
    let exercise = exercises[indexPath.row]

    // Set the title of the cell to be the title of the exercise
    cell.textLabel!.text = exercise.exerciseName
    cell.detailTextLabel!.text = "\(exercise.sets)x\(exercise.reps)"
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DisclosureIndicator
    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if(editingStyle == .Delete ) {
        // Find the Exercise object the user is trying to delete
        let exerciseToDelete = exercises[indexPath.row]

        // Delete it from the managedObjectContext
        managedObjectContext?.deleteObject(exerciseToDelete)

        // Refresh the table view to indicate that it's deleted
        self.fetchExercises()

        // Tell the table view to animate out that row
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
        save()
    }
}

// MARK: UITableViewDelegate
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let exercise = exercises[indexPath.row]
}

let addExerciseAlertViewTag = 0
let addExerciseTextAlertViewTag = 1


@IBAction func addExerciseButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    var namePrompt = UIAlertController(title: "Add Exercise",
        message: "Enter Exercise Name",
        preferredStyle: .Alert)

    var exerciseNameTextField: UITextField?
    namePrompt.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler {
        (textField) -> Void in
        exerciseNameTextField = textField
        textField.placeholder = "Exercise Name"
    }

    namePrompt.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok",
        style: .Default,
        handler: { (action) -> Void in
            if let textField = exerciseNameTextField {
                self.saveNewItem(textField.text, workoutName: workouts.workoutName)
            }
    }))

    self.presentViewController(namePrompt, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func saveNewItem(exerciseName : String, workoutName: String) {

    // Create the new exercise item
    var newExercise = Exercises.createExerciseInManagedObjectContext(self.managedObjectContext!, exerciseName: exerciseName, workoutName: workoutName)

    // Update the array containing the table view row data
    self.fetchExercises()

    // Animate in the new row
    // Use Swift's find() function to figure out the index of the newExercise
    // after it's been added and sorted in our Exercises array
    if let newExerciseIndex = find(exercises, newExercise) {
        // Create an NSIndexPath from the newExerciseIndex
        let newExerciseIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: newExerciseIndex, inSection: 0)
        // Animate in the insertion of this row
        tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([ newExerciseIndexPath ], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
        save()
    }

}

func save() {
    var error : NSError?
    if(managedObjectContext!.save(&error) ) {
        println(error?.localizedDescription)
    }
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if segue.identifier == "exerciseSettings" {
        let ExerciseSettingsDetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as UIViewController
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!
        let exercise = exercises[indexPath.row]
        let destinationTitle = exercise.exerciseName
        ExerciseSettingsDetailViewController.title = destinationTitle
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

Also, here is the function createExerciseInManagedObjectContext that is defined in my Exercises class to add a newExercise:

```
    class func createExerciseInManagedObjectContext(moc: NSManagedObjectContext, exerciseName: String, workoutName: String) -> Exercises {
    let newExercise = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Exercises", inManagedObjectContext: moc) as Exercises

    newExercise.exerciseName = exerciseName
    self.workouts.addObject(workoutName)

    return newExercise
}
```

I can pass the string for the selected Workout (workoutName) into this function but don't know how to set it through the workouts relationship with the Workouts entity.

Here is my Exercises entity:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class Exercises: NSManagedObject {

@NSManaged var exerciseName: String
@NSManaged var sets: NSNumber
@NSManaged var reps: NSNumber
@NSManaged var repWeight: NSNumber
@NSManaged var barWeight: NSNumber
@NSManaged var incrementWeight: NSNumber
@NSManaged var workouts: NSSet

class func createExerciseInManagedObjectContext(moc: NSManagedObjectContext, exerciseName: String, workoutName: String) -> Exercises {
    let newExercise = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Exercises", inManagedObjectContext: moc) as Exercises

    newExercise.exerciseName = exerciseName
    newExercise.workouts.setByAddingObject(workoutName)

    return newExercise
}

}
```

And here's my Workouts entity:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class Workouts: NSManagedObject {

@NSManaged var workoutName: String
@NSManaged var sessions: NSSet
@NSManaged var exercises: NSSet

class func createWorkoutInManagedObjectContext(moc: NSManagedObjectContext, workoutName: String) -> Workouts {
    let newWorkout = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Workouts", inManagedObjectContext: moc) as Workouts
    newWorkout.workoutName = workoutName

    return newWorkout
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you set up the model correctly, the two entities will refer to each other via the relationships. You add the entity to the other one, not its name (which is an attribute).

Core Data should have generated the accessors automatically when you created the `NSManagedObject` subclasses. With these, adding a new (or existing) exercise to a workout is really simple:

```
workout.addExercisesObject(newExercise)
```

*This assumes that your relationship is called* `exercises`.

So it would be actually preferable to pass the actual workout object to the function rather than its name. Don't forget to save.

EDIT:
In order for this to work, you have two options.

Either you have Xcode generate the NSManagedObject subclasses in Objective-C and automatically configure a bridging header. Then you get the accessors without any efforts.

Or you have to implement them yourself. For example:

```
@objc(Exercise)
class Exercise: NSManagedObject {

@NSManaged var workouts: NSSet

    func addWorkoutsObject(value: Workout!) {
        var mutableWorkouts = self.workouts.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableSet
        mutableWorkouts.addObject(value)
        self.workouts = mutableWorkouts as NSSet
    }
}
```

Note that I did not add the key-value coding calls, so KVO will not work unless you add them.

Comment: Thank you, this sounds great. Would I add that to my createExerciseInManagedObjectContext function or the saveNewItem function?

Comment: hmm, just tried this in the saveNewItem function and I get 'Workouts' does not have a member named 'addExerciseObject'?

Comment: This depends on the relationship name. Just look into Workout.swift.

Comment: I edited my answer to explain how to do it. I thought you were using the Objective-C generated subclasses.

Comment: Thanks Mundi, really appreciate your help on this. I've edited my question and added in both the Workouts and Exercises NSManaged classes so you can see how they're setup. I've added the function as you've described above to the Exercises Class and then tried to implement Exercises.addWorkoutsObject(workout) but it's not working. I get an error  saying 'Workouts' is not convertible to 'Exercises'?

Comment: I think I've found another way of achieving this now - I've amended the Exercise class above to show my solution. I use setByAddingObject and pass the workoutName (see above). Do you think this is a good solution? I haven't been able to double check it yet as I still haven't worked out how to limit the exercises shown based on the workout selected.